# Quicksort Java method

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I have a problem with the output of this method:

```
static void quickSort(int[] ar) {

    ArrayList<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> equal = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int num = ar[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i] < num) {
            left.add(ar[i]);
        } else if (ar[i] > num) {
            right.add(ar[i]);
        } else {
            equal.add(ar[i]);
        }
    }
    int[] l = listToArray(left);
    int[] e = listToArray(equal);
    int[] r = listToArray(right);
    ArrayList<Integer> combined = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    combined.addAll(left);
    combined.addAll(equal);
    combined.addAll(right);
    int[] c = listToArray(combined);

    if (l.length > 1) {
        quickSort(l);
    }

    if (r.length > 1) {
        quickSort(r);
    }
    printArray(c);
}
```

**Input (stdin)**

7

5 8 1 3 7 9 2

**Your Output (stdout)**

2 3

1 3 2

7 8 9

1 3 2 5 8 7 9

**Expected Output**

2 3

1 2 3

7 8 9

1 2 3 5 7 8 9

Comment: Please take the 2 or 3 extra seconds to make sure you're using the right tags. And a few minutes to format your code. Check out [ask].

Comment: You never use `l` or `r` after sorting them... what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things going wrong.
1) For a quicksort, you have to sort left and right before combining them back into the combined array.

2) The combined.addAll() was not behaving as expected.  When I had {2,3}, it appended them in reverse order.  Here, I have transferred the values in manual for loops.

3) For the quickSort to return its values, they must be refilled back into the original parameter or returned as a value.  I have filled them in the original parameter.

```
static void quickSort(Integer[] ar) {

    ArrayList<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> equal = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int num = ar[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i] < num) {
            left.add(ar[i]);
        } else if (ar[i] > num) {
            right.add(ar[i]);
        } else {
            equal.add(ar[i]);
        }
    }
    Integer[] l = new Integer[0];
    l = left.toArray(l);
    Integer[] e = new Integer[0];
    e = equal.toArray(e);
    Integer[] r = new Integer[0];
    r = right.toArray(r);
    if (l.length > 1) {
        quickSort(l);
    }

    if (r.length > 1) {
        quickSort(r);
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> combined = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int ai = 0; ai < l.length; ai++)
    {
        combined.add(l[ai]);
    }
    for(int ai = 0; ai < e.length; ai++)
    {
        combined.add(e[ai]);
    }
    for(int ai = 0; ai < r.length; ai++)
    {
        combined.add(r[ai]);
    }
    combined.toArray(ar);
    //printArray(ar);
    System.out.println(combined);
}
```